# TypeError while using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, typeerror

I am using subprocess to capture output of another python file into the current one.Here is my code-

```
    import subprocess
    a= subprocess.run('python3 try1.py', capture_output=True,shell=True)
```

But when I run the code, I get an error-

```
<pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;test2.py&quot;, line 4, in &lt;module&gt;
    c1= subprocess.run(&apos;python3 test2.py&apos;, capture_output=True,shell=True)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py&quot;, line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument &apos;capture_output&apos;
</pre>
```

I am running Python 3.6.8. 
Also, a file named subprocess.py doesn't exist on my PC. It used to, but I deleted it.
Thanks for all help!

Comment: If you read the docs, at the very end of a function description there are changes described depending on Python version. In this case the parameter was added in Python 3.7.

Comment: You need to put the args in a list like: ['python3', 'try1.py'].

Comment: What's new in python 3.7 [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#subprocess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `capture_output` parameter does not exist in Python 3.6 which is what you are using. Hence the error. You can use this instead:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'try1.py'])
```